# Determining CPU usage in WinCE

Tags: c++, windows-ce, cpu-usage

I want to be able to get the current % CPU usage in a C++ program running under Wince.

I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859476.aspx) that states where the source code is but I cannot find it in my platform builder installation - I expect this is because it isn't the Windows Automotive platform.

Does anyone know where I can find this source code or (even better) know how I can get this information directly? i.e. what DLL / function calls to make etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since GetProcessTimes doesn't exist in CE, you have to calculate this.

You have to start with [the toolhelp APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915058.aspx) to enumerate the processes and the threads in the processes.  You then call [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909163(v=MSDN.10).aspx) for each thread and add all that up.

Bear in mind that the act of calculating this info will affect the CPU utilization.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responsve.  I think I may have been a little ambiguous in my question.  What I am really looking for is a way to get % CPU usage times.  How can I find this out?

Comment: Just like the top.exe application, you have to calculate it. The way to do that is to iterate through all threads in all processes and add up all of the thread times then divide the time it took to calculate by that amount.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that [`GetIdleTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885626.aspx) (or [`CeGetIdleTimeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154739%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx) on WEC7 or newer) works well for calculating system-wide processor usage. Sample code for calculating processor idle time percentage is shown on [`GetIdleTime` MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885626.aspx). Obviously, processor utilization percentage can then be calculated by subtracting the idle time percentage from 100.

The MSDN page does warn that support for `GetIdleTime` is dependent on OAL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using the toolhelp APIs to calculate the CPU usage, you need to take two measurements, then calculate the difference. when doing so, you won't know how much CPU any threads that were terminated before the second sample took.

So, applications that often create short-lived threads will not be represented properly in your result.

Comment: Can you explain why two measurements are required for CPU usage? That is, please explain what the thing you measure shows (that the difference shows CPU usage)

Comment: each measurement gives you the total number of clock ticks used by a thread.  the usage is calculated as  `(secondmesurement - firstmeasurement)/measurementinterval * 100 %`

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Remote Task Monitor](https://www.osletek.com/pg/2186/Remote_Task_Monitor_for_Embedded_Devices). It will let you get the current % CPU usage of your process (or thread), exactly what you are looking for. It also is very light weight, does not impact your device much.